# Need help getting this simple Fahrenheit to Celsius application working in java

Tags: java, swing, event-handling, awt

I need this application to convert the number entered by the user in the `JTextField` into **celsius** and display it in a `JLabel`. It seems to be having problems parsing the the data entered into a double? This is one error among many.
 Can anyone help me figure out whats wrong? (I've only entered double values in the text field when testing it out and it still wont change it to a double.)

```
public class TempConvertGUI extends JFrame{
    private JLabel result;
    private final JTextField input;

    public TempConvertGUI()
    {
        super("Fahrenheit to Celsius Application");

        setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        //TempConvert convert=new TempConvert();

        input=new JTextField(10);
        input.setToolTipText("Enter degrees in fahrenheit here.");
        input.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            private double temp;
            private String string;

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                if(event.getSource()==input)
                {
                    remove(result);
                    if(event.getActionCommand()==null)
                        result.setText(null);
                    else
                    {
                        temp=Double.parseDouble(event.getActionCommand());
                        string=String.format("%d degrees Celsius", convertToCelsius(temp));
                        result.setText(string);;
                    }
                    add(result);
                }
            }

        });
        add(input);

        result=new JLabel();
        add(result);

    }

    private double convertToCelsius(double fahrenheit)
    {
        return (5/9)*(fahrenheit-32);
    }
}
```

Comment: Rather then manually parsing the results, consider using a `JFormattedTextField` or `JSpinner` which perform validation of the content based on the rules you provide automatically.  See [How to Use Formatted Text Fields](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/formattedtextfield.html) and [How to Use Spinners](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/spinner.html) for more details

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. The ActionCommand for the the JTextField was never set, so it will be an empty String. If you want to parse the data within the JTextField, then get its value and parse that value (eg `temp=Double.parseDouble(input.getText());`)
2. See the API for [formatting strings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax) - use an `%f` to parse floating point values
3. No need to add and remove the `result` JLabel in ActionPerformed, it has already been added to the UI - just set it's text
4. `(5/9)` is integer math, if you want floating point math then specify one of the numbers as the proper data type: `(5/9d)`

Comment: AHHH! Thanks man! Forgot about having to use %f. I ended up editing my code in tons of stupid ways when that was the only issue I was having apparently lol. It works now though! Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

It seems you got this exception

```
java.util.IllegalFormatConversionException: d != java.lang.Double
```

And it is because of this line of code

```
string=String.format("%d degrees Celsius", convertToCelsius(temp));
```

`%d` represents an integer; you want to use `%f` for a double (`convertToCelsius` returns a double).

So change it to

```
string=String.format("%f degrees Celsius", convertToCelsius(temp));
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `temp=Double.parseDouble(event.getActionCommand());`, you should be parsing the input from `input.getText()`.